# Mongodb Vs Azure Documentdb which is better and why

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

> I am going to use mongodb, but being a .net developer I am looking into
>   Azure Documentdb.
>
> I want to know.
>
> 1. Anyone is really using Azure Documentdb on production.
> 2. Is azure Documentbd is as good as in performance as mongodb.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Anyone is really using Azure Documentdb on production.

R: Microsoft is using on MSN portal and One Note.

> 2. Is azure Documentbd is as good as in performance as mongodb.

Yes, it is.

Mongo is more mature, but Azure DocumentDB is always being improved. I suppose that you are going to host your app on Azure, so I would go with Azure DocumentDB because it uses SSDs and I won't need to handle with the infrastructure  stuff.

Comment: yes have looked into that but have not found any performance comparison document or anything else on the web. Also the mongodb on azure is costly. i did setup replica set of my own on 3 azure centos machines to save money but again maintaining them is a pain and even c# driver for mongodb  is buggy.

Comment: You're right. I can't find any performance test either, but if you face performance problems you can scale to Microsoft and let them handle for you.